# How do I make binlog-format=ROW the start up default in the /etc/my.cnf file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf, binlog

I can run the query **SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW'** and it works for that session.

How do I make this setting stick after stopping and restarting MySQL?

NOTE: I am on version  5.5.19 of MySQL (with Moodle) and I just upgraded from MyISAM to InnoDB and therefore need this new setting.

I have tried adding these two commands (separately) to my.cnf: **binlog-format=ROW** and **binlog_format=ROW** and neither work. I have stopped and restarted MySQL every time I changed the my.cnf.

The error I get without this being set is the nefarious error message:

Debug info: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

Answer (score 17):

I think your problem may stem from where you wrote the directive

Make sure you place the option under the `[mysqld]` header in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format = ROW
```

If you place it under any other header, the mysqld process will not see it.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This worked! Yes, it was under another heading.

Answer (score 0):

3 Values for binlog_format

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format = ROW
```

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format = STATEMENT
```

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format = MIXED
```